# makefile rebuilding everytime when object file dumped in other dir

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

I have a makefile which keeps on rebuilding the c++ source everytime i do compilation. I figured out the reason is i am dumping object files in a separate directory.
One line from make file is :

```
$(CPP_COMPILER) $(COMPILE_FLAGS) $(RELEASE_OPT_FLAGS) -c Test.cpp $(INCLUDE_PATH) -o objfiles/$(OUTDIR)/Test.o
```

Can i put some rule with which make first check this dir (objfiles) and if not needed do not re-build the source everytime?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What you are requesting is **precisely** how Make works out of the box, provided your `Makefile` is correct.  You are not showing us the entire file, so we can't troubleshoot it for you; but by your description, your dependencies for this target are not properly declared.

Answer (score 1):

You should make the rule itself refer to the correct path:

```
objfiles/$(OUTDIR)/Test.o: Test.cpp
  $(CPP_COMPILER) $(COMPILE_FLAGS) $(RELEASE_OPT_FLAGS) -c Test.cpp $(INCLUDE_PATH) -o objfiles/$(OUTDIR)/Test.o
```

If you still want `Test.o` as the makefile target, you can easily add one then:

```
Test.o: objfiles/$(OUTDIR)/Test.o
```

Comment: thanks for the comment. But following this i am falling in another problem. so $(OUTDIR) is a variable which i create as follows -  GCC_VERSION=`gcc --version| cut -d " " -f 3|head -1`
OUTDIR=gcc_$(GCC_VERSION)_$(PLATFORM)
Now when i try to use it in target. make shout out couple of errors.

Comment: @user888270: You are trying to solve multiple problems at once; *divide and conquer.* Before you try to use that variable in a command, verify that it has the value you think it has, and that the directory you intend to use actually exists.